# "Daydream(ing)" Vs "Woolgather(ing)" Vs "Fantasizing"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

What are the current and common idioms used to describe indulging in **purposeless** and **purposeful** thoughts?

I know two idioms that in my opinion one of them is used to describe the positive (purposeful) thinking and the other one for useless (purposeless) thoughts:

A. **Woolgathering** (the verb: to woolgather), which seems to be [archaic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324726/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-gathering-wool). {This is a negative one in my eyes, but I'm not sure first of all I am right in this regard. Then, whether it is used in current English.}

B. **Daydreaming** (the verb: to daydream), which based on dictionary definition seems to be something [positive.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/daydream)

**Examples1:**

> 1. It is good to .............. sometimes. To have a vision and keep thinking about it all the time, can make you more ambitious and increase your motives to get what you want.
> 2. You are always just thinking about your goals. I think it's time to stop .................. . Roll up your sleeves and get to work.

I wonder what shall I use in each case above? 
Do my offers fit these examples?
If not, please let me know what are the most appropriate and common idioms for these cases?

**Added:**

Also, I need to compare "fantasize" with these two.

[**Fantasize:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/fantasize)

> To think about something very pleasant that is unlikely to happen.

I wonder which one is positive and which one is negative and Which ones are synonymous?

Comment: I think of "daydreaming" and "woolgathering" as both being towards the purposeless end of the spectrum - with woolgathering having a more critical tone.

Comment: Are they interchangeable @user888379? I wonder which type of English native you are? I mean AE/BE? As an American native (sumelic) believes there is no such a term as "woolgathering" in common English.

Comment: Collins seems to regard them as synonyms - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/woolgathering . _Woolgathering_ is a perfectly familiar term to me (British, 60+) and I think of it as idly letting your mind wander, while _fantasizing_ is more consciously imagining a desirable situation.

Comment: Uh @sumelic, sorry for the mistake. Yes, I meant suspectus's answer in my comment.

Comment: @A-friend I'm an American, more specifically a New Englander. I never thought of "woolgathering" as a particularly exotic word; a little old-fashioned, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much @user888379. +1

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of "woolgathering" before.

For a expression with possibly negative undertones, there is `head in the clouds`.

> e.g. He was not listening, he had his head in the clouds.

For thinking in a positive sense, the verbs `to deliberate` or `to ponder` could be used.

> e.g. She deliberated before purchasing her ticket.
>
> The young man pondered over applying for a university course.

Fantasize would be used for an incredible or wild daydream. Deliberate and ponder would be used usually for more serious thinking.

Comment: @A-friend post edited for what it's worth.